# empty /etc/skel still adds default directories

Tags: elementary-os, useradd

I am using elementary freya and creating a new user with

```
root# useradd -s /bin/bash -mk /etc/skel -d /home/secret -c otherme agentb24
```

and my `/etc/skel` is empty and I also want my new user home to be empty.
the problem is when I logout and log back in as new user my home is populated with defaults (document, videos, pictures), also when I check my newly created home folder before I logout it is empty just like I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those directories are not created by `/etc/skel` in most cases, but instead by your desktop environment (specifically its file manager).

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out. I changed a `xdg-user-dirs-update` to `enabled=False` in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf`. That seemed to work. XDG must be my file manager, I did't know that. Thanks again.

Comment: XDG literally means "X Desktop Group", which was an old name for freedesktop.org - a project that aims to improve interoperability and collaboration in X11 desktop development. The `xdg-user-dir` and `xdg-user-dirs-update` are tools to allow any compliant desktops maintain a set of special directories (e.g. `~/Desktop`) with localizable names.